# Server program is stuck at send

Tags: c, networking, send

I am building a server client model in C. The clients connects to the server and they start exchanging data. However, the user can end the client at any time in the program, but the server is not notified about it. The server keeps sending that data even after the client is closed.
I was in the impression that send function will return -1 if the server is unable to send the data, but my server program just stuck at send

```
if((byteSent = send(new_fd, fileContents,  strlen(fileContents), 0)) == -1){ //
```

the program just halts at the above line.

How do I overcome this problem?

//Code

```
   exitT = 0;
    //execution_count = 1;
    for(i=0;i<execution_count;i++)
    {  
        sleep(time_delay);

        //getting the current time on the server machine
        time_t t;
        time(&t);

        char *time=ctime(&t);
        printf("The Execution time at server =  %s\n",time);

        system(exec_command);

       /*Open the file, get file size, read the contents and close the file*/

        // Open the file
        fp = fopen(fileName,"r");

        // Get File Size
        fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
        dataLength = ftell(fp);
        rewind(fp);                

        fileContents = (char*)malloc(dataLength+1);
       // Read File
       fread(fileContents,1,dataLength,fp);
       fileContents[dataLength] = '\0';

        // Close file
         fclose(fp);    

       printf("sockfd = %d \n",new_fd);
       // send file length to client
       rc=send(new_fd, &dataLength,  sizeof(dataLength), 0) ;

       printf("length of client data = %d \n",rc);

        printf("sockfd = %d \n",new_fd);
       // send time to client
       rc=send(new_fd, time,  strlen(time), 0) ;

       printf("length of client time = %d \n",rc);

       usleep(20000);

       // Send file contents to Client
       while(dataLength>0){
            printf("sockfd = %d \n",new_fd);
            if((byteSent = send(new_fd, fileContents,  strlen(fileContents), 0)) == -1){
                printf("bytes sent = %d \n",byteSent);
                exitT = 1;
                break;
            }
            dataLength-=byteSent;
       }

       //Delete the log file 
       sprintf(deleteCommand,"rm %s",fileName);
       system(deleteCommand);
       if(exitT == 1)
           break;
     }

      bzero(fileName,sizeof(fileName));
      bzero(exec_command,sizeof(exec_command));
      bzero(deleteCommand,sizeof(deleteCommand));

      //decClientNum();
      kill(parent_id,SIGALRM);
      close(new_fd);  // parent doesn't need this
      printf("STATUS = CLOSED\n");

      exit(0);
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are coding for a Linux or Posix system.

When a syscall like [send](http://linux.die.net/man/2/send) fails it returns -1 and *sets the `errno`*; you very probably should use [errno](http://linux.die.net/man/3/errno) to find out why it failed.

You could use [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) to find out which syscalls are done by your sever, or some other one. Of course, use also the `gdb` debugger.

You very probably need to multiplex inputs or outputs. The system calls doing that are [poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll), [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) (and related `ppoll` and `pselect`). Read e.g. the [select_tut(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select_tut) man page.

You may want to use (or at least to study the source code of) existing event oriented libraries like `libevent`, `libev` etc.. (Both Gtk and Qt frameworks provide also their own, which might be used even outside of GUI applications).

I strongly suggest reading about [advanced unix programming](http://basepath.com/aup/) and [unix network programing](http://www.unpbook.com/) (and perhaps also about [advanced linux programming](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)).

Comment: Usually people cannot use libs like that in homework assignments. It would pretty much defeat the purpose of working with the low-level socket functions and learning how to use them.

Comment: But they can at least study their source code and learn a lot.

Comment: Indeed - but for a simple assignment it's usually way too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you're using a tcp protocol and the server is waiting for an ACK. Try using udp if you want your connection to be asynchronous.

Comment: It is a part of my networking assignment and I have to use TCP

Answer (score 0):

From the man page: No indication of failure to deliver is implicit in a  send().   Locally detected errors are indicated by a return value of -1.

Proably something like this might help: http://stefan.buettcher.org/cs/conn_closed.html

Comment: The example shows that the server is receiving something from the client and if there is nothing in the pipe, it treats the client being closed. But in my program, the client is closed when the server is sending data to the client. my server program halts at the send() function. and the receive flags doesn't work with send() function.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am pretty late in the party, but I think this answer might help someone.

If space is not available at the sending socket to hold the message to be transmitted, and the socket file descriptor does not have O_NONBLOCK set, send() shall block until space is available.

When send() function gets stuck, there might be a situation like, TCP window size has become 0. It happens when the other end of the connection is not consuming received data.

There might be a scenario like this, the receiving end process is running by GDB and segfault occurred.

1. The TCP connection remains established.
2. Data is being send continuously.
3. The receiver end is not consuming it.

Consequently the receiver TCP window size will keep decreasing and you can send data till it is greater than zero. Once it becomes 0, send() function will get stuck forever.

As the situation mentioned in the question is not a scenario of closed connection. When a process writes something on a closed TCP connection, it receives a signal SIGPIPE. Default handler of SIGPIPE terminates the process. So, in a closed connection scenario if you are not using your own SIGPIPE handler then process should be terminated by default handler whenever something is written on the socket.